# Java - ExecutorService stops processing thread after a while

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have this code that runs in a JBoss container and has been running successfully for the last couple of years. However, now the runnable code executes fine for few weeks, and then it just stops processing, and the execute method does nothing. There are no exceptions or errors.

```
private static ExecutorService schedulerExecuter = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private String id;

public void schedule(Context context) {
    
    schedulerExecuter.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                    Logger.error(e);
                }
            });
            
            try {
                SomeService service = new SomeService();
                service.sendAndReceive(connectorId);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Logger.error(e);
            } finally {
                Logger.debug("Done with Scheduler Thread - [Connector Id - " + connectorId + "]");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The only thing that has changed in the past few months is the JBoss and JDK versions.
Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: OK. So your executor has a single thread.  If (just) one of the tasks gets stuck for some reasons, that would cause the thread to block ... and no more tasks would be run.  Look for stuck threads.  (Start with `jstack` ...)

Comment: By the way, a tip: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/